# R - Delete observations where column text has Unicode <U+XXXX>

Tags: r, unicode

I am using the 'searchConsoleR' package to get some information from the Google Webmaster Tool for my domain.

```
data <- search_analytics(siteURL = website, 
                         startDate = loopDate, 
                         endDate = loopDate, 
                         dimensions = download_dimensions, 
                         searchType = type,
                         rowLimit = 5000)
```

I want to delete all observations where data$query contains Unicode in format `<U+0308><u+0199>, etc.`, that correspond to languages like russian, chinese, etc.

While querying the query directly in console I get the string in a human-readable format,

```
> data$query[47230]
[1] "职业道德"
```

I get a non human-readable format while navigating the source pane:

[image: Unicode show as <U+XXX>]

I know, that I could use `grepl` for conditionally deleting those observations, but it only works if I give the actual character (f.i. 职), and not the  format. I do not know if there is a easy way to do it without having to create a mapping of characters in Russian, chinese, thai, etc.

Here a `dput()`of a portion of my data:

```
> dput(data[,2][47217:47250])
c("<U+043B><U+0438><U+043D><U+0434><U+0435>", "<U+043B><U+0438><U+043D><U+0434><U+0435> <U+0438><U+043D><U+0436><U+0438><U+043D><U+0438><U+0440><U+0438><U+043D><U+0433> <U+0440><U+0443><U+0441>", 
"<U+043B><U+0438><U+043D><U+0434><U+0435> <U+0438><U+043D><U+0436><U+0438><U+043D><U+0438><U+0440><U+0438><U+043D><U+0433> <U+0440><U+0443><U+0441> <U+043E><U+0442><U+0437><U+044B><U+0432><U+044B>", 
"<U+043B><U+0438><U+043D><U+0434><U+0435> <U+0438><U+043D><U+0436><U+0438><U+043D><U+0438><U+0440><U+0438><U+043D><U+0433> <U+0440><U+0443><U+0441> <U+0441><U+0430><U+043C><U+0430><U+0440><U+0430>", 
"<U+0442><U+0438><U+043B><U+044C><U+043C><U+0430><U+043D> <U+0438><U+043D><U+0436><U+0438><U+043D><U+0438><U+0440><U+0438><U+043D><U+0433>", 
"<U+044D><U+043A><U+0441><U+043F><U+0435><U+0440><U+0442><U+0438><U+0437><U+0430> <U+043E><U+0431><U+0443><U+0432><U+0438> <U+0441><U+0430><U+043C><U+0430><U+0440><U+0430>", 
"<U+0644><U+064A><U+0646><U+062F><U+0629>", "<U+6DB2><U+5316><U+5929><U+7136><U+6C14>", 
"<U+6DB2><U+5316><U+5929><U+7136><U+6C14>", "<U+6DB2><U+5316><U+5929><U+7136><U+6C14>", 
"<U+6DB2><U+5316><U+5929><U+7136><U+6C14>", "<U+6DB2><U+5316><U+5929><U+7136><U+6C14>", 
"<U+6DB2><U+5316><U+5929><U+7136><U+6C23>", "<U+804C><U+4E1A><U+9053><U+5FB7>", 
"<U+9053><U+5FB7><U+898F><U+7BC4>", "1- hexene", "1-hexen", "1-hexen", 
"1-hexen", "1-hexene", "1 hexen", "1 hexen", "5083-0", "5083o in stock", 
"83342 tacherting", "83342 tacherting", "83342 tacherting", "aamonia", 
"abtrennung", "abu dhabi cracker", "acetylen dresden", "achema 2015", 
"acid gas", "acid gas removal")
```

And here my `sessionInfo()`

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=German_Germany.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=German_Germany.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=German_Germany.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                   
[5] LC_TIME=German_Germany.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices
[4] utils     datasets  methods  
[7] base     

other attached packages:
[1] tm_0.6-2            
[2] NLP_0.1-9           
[3] stringr_1.1.0       
[4] dplyr_0.5.0         
[5] searchConsoleR_0.2.1
[6] rJava_0.9-8         

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.7      
 [2] magrittr_1.5     
 [3] devtools_1.12.0  
 [4] munsell_0.4.3    
 [5] xtable_1.8-2     
 [6] colorspace_1.2-7 
 [7] R6_2.2.0         
 [8] httr_1.2.1       
 [9] plyr_1.8.4       
[10] tools_3.3.1      
[11] parallel_3.3.1   
[12] grid_3.3.1       
[13] gtable_0.2.0     
[14] DBI_0.5-1        
[15] googleAuthR_0.4.0
[16] withr_1.0.2      
[17] htmltools_0.3.5  
[18] openssl_0.9.5    
[19] lazyeval_0.2.0   
[20] assertthat_0.1   
[21] digest_0.6.10    
[22] tibble_1.2       
[23] shiny_0.14.1     
[24] ggplot2_2.2.0    
[25] curl_2.2         
[26] mime_0.5         
[27] memoise_1.0.0    
[28] slam_0.1-38      
[29] stringi_1.1.2    
[30] scales_0.4.1     
[31] jsonlite_1.1     
[32] httpuv_1.3.3
```

Comment: a `dput()` of a representative slice of the data frame (with & without the target chars) wld be useful as wld a the output of `sessionInfo()` so we can see your system configuration.

Comment: you can use `grepl` with a pattern allowing only regular chars, something like `grepl('[[:print:]]',data)` should do to get back only matching records. (maybe with `Sys.setlocale(LC_ALL=C)` before.

Comment: (but all in all, I don't get the problem at all, it's just Rstudio viewer not handling Unicode characters...)

Comment: @Tensibai, my problem is that I want to delete all the observations where query contains <U+XXXX> or similar. Lets say it like, all characters other than those from "western" languages (spanish, english, german, suomi...). Your `grepl('[[:print:]]',data)` solution removes most observations, but not all of them. I believe, however, that only russian characters survived

Comment: @agustin Really, what's the point of removing those observations ? Just because Rstudio viewer can't show them cleanly ?

Comment: And if your data are really what you pasted in your question: `grepl('^(?!.*<U+)',data, perl+TRUE)` should do. But I really think the proper is a `print` representation of UTF8 characters more than something else.